# Why does adding font-weight:bold; disable other font styles?

Tags: html, css, fonts

My stylesheet has:

```
.application_title {font-size: 3em; color: darkred; }
```

and that works great.  But when I add `font-weight:bold`, i.e.

```
.application_title {font-size: 3em; color: darkred; font-weight: bold; }
```

I lose the other effects.

Why could this be?

Comment: Seems fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/dum5h/

Comment: On my Ubuntu FF 7 it works perfectly. You could try adding a semicolon after the font-weight.

Comment: Can you regenerate/upload that somewhere ?

Comment: Adding only `font-weight: bold` will make no difference to any of those other properties. The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Works in Chrome, FF and IE8 here: http://jsfiddle.net/KWVy6/

Comment: added the semi-colon. Same in all browsers, etc.

Comment: Can you re-build it in jsFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not a missing semicolon, I cannot imagine anything but that you have some other css elsewhere overriding it. You could maybe also try font-weight: 800;

Comment: ..and what font are you using?

Comment: ow. I haven't voted any answers (for this question) down, is there an issue?  Remember down-votes are not personal, they are done because the answer is not correct or constructive in my opinion.  Some of my own older answers (before I learned more) I would down-vote!  The community relies on downvotes, 1 or two don't matter and if there enough members that agree there will be plenty of upvotes.  It's just how SO works.

Comment: sorry, i did not mean to come across as pissy, and certainly, i have no idea of knowing who votes what where. 0 just seems good enough for "not working". i beg your pardon.

Comment: @boblet, font-weight:700 is the exact number for bold.

Comment: The other two answers were probably downvoted because they're useless. One answer only adds a semicolon which is optional anyway, and the other answer is not going to make any difference. Your `font-weight: 800` suggestion is also useless. How is changing the font weight going to affect whether the text is red ("I lose the other effects.") or not?

Comment: On one level, the two "useless" suggestions are not in fact all that useless, because we do not know if the good man who asked the question actually pasted his code, and if not, a semicolon could have eluded him, in a place where it would actually matter. Yes, I know the last one does not need a semicolon. 

A missing semicolon is the first, obvious possibility. The next would be a missing curly bracket higher up. >

Comment: < My font-weight:800 is not very likely to do anything, you are right there. I added it as an afterthought to my otherwise more constructive comment. Maybe this is just how I work, but I prefer to test out the small "possible", "unlikely" and "no way" ideas first, before I start machete my way through a whole stylesheet. I would like to focus on the idea that something else is overriding it, but I do not know, as I cannot see the rest of the css. WIth the information given, that is kind of the end of the process for me at least.

@Michael Durrant - share more of the css?

Comment: well thirtydot and bovlet (sorry for the absence) the final result was.... the font I was using!  I've recently started using @font-face and I had obtained 'Matchbook' (a cool tall thin font).  Only problem is that it doesn't have any bold (or 'em') font.  So using font-weight bold with any tags then messes them up, i.e. they loose all the other styles.  Maybe that can be changed with the order of the elements, not sure.  Anyway, I have upvoted boblet and also I have given thirtydot some upvotes too.  Thanks Guys!  This was a classic case of 'look elsewhere' !

Comment: Happy to hear the solution! That is why I asked at the top about what font you had there. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: You need to use `@thirtydot` in your comment if you [want it to reach me](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-reply). That `@font-face` could be the problem didn't even occur to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you are missing a semicolon in your CSS.

```
.application_title {font-size: 3em; color: darkred; font-weight: bold; }
```